# Trying to fetch the attributes only from the current product post (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object, foreach

I have a weird a dilemma here that I'm trying to figure. Basically I'm using method on Woocommerce to fetch the product attributes from each product post using the snippet below.

`$productAttributesObject = $product->get_attributes('')`

Then store those attributes into an array

```
foreach ($productAttributesObject  as $i => $value) {
    $singleArray[] = $value->get_options();
}
```

Somehow, it seems that the foreach I've created to does not clear values from the product post basically just stacks them together. To explain it clearly I have two product post

One product contains an attribute called `Fruits` which contains the following terms:

`100% Orange Juice | Apple | Pear | Pineapple | Passionfruit | Red Dragonfruit | Baobab Powder | Grapeseed Extract`

The other products contains an attribute called `Color` which contains the following terms:

`Red | Green`

My expectations that for each loop it appends the attributes into a array

**Expectations**

**Product 1 Attributes**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "400 ml"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "1L"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "2L"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "100% Orange Juice"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Pear"
    [3]=>
    string(9) "Pineapple"
    [4]=>
    string(12) "Passionfruit"
    [5]=>
    string(15) "Red Dragonfruit"
    [6]=>
    string(13) "Baobab Powder"
    [7]=>
    string(17) "Grapeseed Extract"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
}
```

---

**Product 2 Attributes**

```
array(1) {
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Red"
  }
}
```

What I got was the array seems to be stacking on top of each other and getting the attributes from the previous product instead of getting only the attributes from the current product

**Reality**

**Product 1 Attributes**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "400 ml"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "1L"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "2L"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "100% Orange Juice"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Pear"
    [3]=>
    string(9) "Pineapple"
    [4]=>
    string(12) "Passionfruit"
    [5]=>
    string(15) "Red Dragonfruit"
    [6]=>
    string(13) "Baobab Powder"
    [7]=>
    string(17) "Grapeseed Extract"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
}
```

---

**Product 2 Attributes**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "400 ml"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "1L"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "2L"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "100% Orange Juice"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Pear"
    [3]=>
    string(9) "Pineapple"
    [4]=>
    string(12) "Passionfruit"
    [5]=>
    string(15) "Red Dragonfruit"
    [6]=>
    string(13) "Baobab Powder"
    [7]=>
    string(17) "Grapeseed Extract"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Red"
  }
}
```

As you can see the attribute color is at the last index with the rest of the attributes from the previous post.

How can programmatically fetch only the attributes from the current post only? Here is a complete snippet of the code

```
<ul class="product-list">
              
              <?php 

        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'product',
          'posts_per_page' => 2
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

      ?>
      
      <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
      
      <?php global $product ?>
      
                <li class="product-post"
                
                    <?php 
        
          $productAttributesObject = $product->get_attributes('');
                
        foreach ($productAttributesObject  as $i => $value) {
           $singleArray[] = $value->get_options();
        }
      
        foreach($singleArray as $val) { 
            foreach ($val as $v) { 
                $completeList[] = $v; 
            }
        }
        
        $arrayLowerCase = array_map('strtolower', $completeList);
        $arrayConvert = str_replace(' ', '-', $arrayLowerCase);
        $attributeTerms = implode(' ', $arrayConvert);
      
                  ?>
                  
                  data-type="<?php echo $attributeTerms ?>"
                
                 >

                  
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                      
                      <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'product-image')) ?>
                        <div class="product-coaster"></div>
                    </div>
    
                    <h2 class="product-name"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                    <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                </li>
                
                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                
                <p>no post</p>
                
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: You need to re-initialise `$singleArray` and `$completeList` for each product, add `$singleArray = array(); $completeList = array();` before the `foreach ($productAttributesObject  as $i => $value)` loop

Comment: Hahaha damn, I didn't know it was that effing simple. Here I was pulling my hair trying to figure this out

Comment: We've all been there...

Comment: @Nick Can you please turn your comment into an Answer so I can mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-initialise `$singleArray` and `$completeList` for each product. To do this, add

```
$singleArray = array();
$completeList = array();
```

before this line:

```
foreach ($productAttributesObject  as $i => $value) {
```